# PnP powershell change sharepoint list items

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I want to update a number of items on a sharepoint list.
The list has a field called servers and the servers are equal to a list of servers kept in an .txt file.

In short I want to update the farm field to prod for all servers that are in the file (Server field on the list).

The method would be to use Set-PnPListItem, but in combination with:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content $pathRead)
```

I can't get it to work.

I tried using -Identity $_.Server -Values @{"Farm" = "PROD"} but it returns:
Set-PnPListItem : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null..

Is there a way to update the list this way?

Edit: Bigger script sample

```
$pathRead = "D:\CertScipts\Servrar_Prod.txt"
Import-Module "C:\PNP\SharePointPnPPowerShell2019\3.6.1902.2\SharePointPnPPowerShell2019.psd1"
if ($cred -eq $null)
{ 
$cred = Get-Credential
}
Connect-PnPOnline "-" -Credentials $cred
$list = Get-PnPList "Certifikat Auto"

foreach($line in Get-Content $pathRead) 
{  
Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity -Values @{"Farm" = "PROD"}
}
```

Edit2
Can I use a camel-query, Get-PnPListitem -list $list -Query that uses $line to just list the items that have a server from my .txt file?

Comment: If I understand that each `$line` in `$pathRead` is a server name that you want to pass to `Set-PnPListItem`, then you should specify the `-Identity` parameter as `-Identity $line`.  `$_` won't have a value here or, if it does, it's not related to or set by the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Your on point on what I want to do. But even with $line.$_ or $line.$_server it won't do the trick.

I  updated the Question with a bigger sample.

Comment: `$line` is a `[String]` instance representing a line of text read from the file at `$pathRead`; it's the value itself — and none of its properties — that are needed here, so you need to pass it exactly as I stated: `-Identity $line -Values @{"Farm" = "PROD"}`.

Comment: I did what you suggested, Set-PnPListItem : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

With that said if I only use $line as identity, it wont understand which column to update?

Comment: I've never worked with this module but seeing the error message for a `[NullReferenceException]` strikes me as an internal error being allowed to leak out.  There are no blank lines in the `$pathRead` file?  And you're sure `Get-PnPList` returned a value?  You could pass `$line` or a string literal (e.g. `'MyServer'`) or `$myCustomType.Server.Name` to `-Identity` and the parameter variable will receive that value without any way to know the structure it came from; there must be another mechanism by which it maps it to a particular column.

Comment: It would seem that's what the `-Values` parameter is doing: for the list item `$line`, set the `"Farm"` field to `"PROD"`.  The only other thing I can suggest is maybe updating that module from [this](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell) or [this](https://github.com/pnp/powershell) project in case that error message is the result of buggy behavior.

Comment: Identity can't be equal to the line, it's the id number of the row so I need to do prefilter and add some more stuff, will look into a camel query that filters server column based on $line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity -Values @{"Farm" = "PROD"}
```

You haven't specified the Identity parameter (the item id). ie.

```
Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity 1 -Values @{"Farm" = "PROD"}
```

Comment: I figured that was a part of the probleem hence my last comment, I decided to skip this whole idea and wrewrote the mainscript that adds the items to handle it from the start instead.